# Duda con phpMailerAutoload SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP

Tags: php, phpmailer

Les comento que es la primera vez que envío correos usando gmail con phpMailer.
Pero tengo una duda, cuando envío un correo me manda este mensaje:

```
2017-09-06 15:20:01 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP e65sm92479oia.15 - gsmtp 
2017-09-06 15:20:01 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost 
2017-09-06 15:20:01 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [187.226.184.106] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME 250-STARTTLS 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-PIPELINING 250-CHUNKING 250 SMTPUTF8 
2017-09-06 15:20:01 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS 
2017-09-06 15:20:01 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS 
2017-09-06 15:20:01 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost 
2017-09-06 15:20:01 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [187.226.184.106] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-PIPELINING 250-CHUNKING 250 SMTPUTF8 
2017-09-06 15:20:01 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN 
2017-09-06 15:20:01 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6 
2017-09-06 15:20:01 CLIENT -> SERVER: YXJtYW5kb2JvbGFuaW9zQGdtYWlsLmNvbQ== 
2017-09-06 15:20:02 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6 
2017-09-06 15:20:02 CLIENT -> SERVER: RHVua2VsaGVpdF85Mw== 
2017-09-06 15:20:02 SERVER -> CLIENT: 235 2.7.0 Accepted 
2017-09-06 15:20:02 CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM: 
2017-09-06 15:20:02 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.1.0 OK e65sm92479oia.15 - gsmtp 
2017-09-06 15:20:02 CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO: 
2017-09-06 15:20:02 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.1.5 OK e65sm92479oia.15 - gsmtp 
2017-09-06 15:20:02 CLIENT -> SERVER: DATA 
2017-09-06 15:20:02 SERVER -> CLIENT: 354 Go ahead e65sm92479oia.15 - gsmtp 
2017-09-06 15:20:02 CLIENT -> SERVER: Date: Wed, 6 Sep 2017 15:20:01 +0000 
2017-09-06 15:20:02 CLIENT -> SERVER: To: JOEL 
2017-09-06 15:20:02 CLIENT -> SERVER: From: joel@gmail.com 
2017-09-06 15:20:02 CLIENT -> SERVER: Subject: Recuperar Password 
2017-09-06 15:20:02 CLIENT -> SERVER: Message-ID: 
2017-09-06 15:20:02 CLIENT -> SERVER: X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.16 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) 
2017-09-06 15:20:02 CLIENT -> SERVER: MIME-Version: 1.0 
2017-09-06 15:20:02 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1 
2017-09-06 15:20:02 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit 2017-09-06 15:20:02   CLIENT -> SERVER: 
2017-09-06 15:20:02 CLIENT -> SERVER: Hola JOEL:
Has solicitado una nueva contraseña, 
2017-09-06 15:20:02 CLIENT -> SERVER
```

El correo sí se envía, solo que manda este mensaje después de enviar el email, ¿es un error? ¿Alguien sabe qué significa esto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No es ningún error, tan solo es información de diagnóstico. En algún sitio tienes activada la depuración SMTP. Puedes desactivarla haciendo 
esto antes de enviar el correo:

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
$mail->send();
```

Puedes encontrar más información en la [documentación](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/SMTP-Debugging) de PHPMailer

Comment: Funciona, gracias